# Сохранение, чтение и удаление временных файлов

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

У меня в приложении пользователь выбирает фотографии из определённых папок. Эти картинки преобразовываются и мне нужно сохранять их временно на устройство. Потом после того как пользователь выбрал несколько картинок, они отправляются на сайт, а временные файлы удаляются. Но что-то у меня не получается ничего. 
Меня на данные момент интересуют простейшие операции - создание/сохранение, чтение, удаление файла во временной директории.

Я нашёл урок http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/file-management-tutorial-ios8-swift. Но как я понял он для более ранней версии свифт, а у меня swift 2.3.
Я когда задаю следующий код, он ругается, на то что там присутствует аргумент error:

```swift
func enumerateDirectory() -> String? {
    var error: NSError?
    let filesInDirectory =  fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(tmpDir, error: &error) as? [String]

    if let files = filesInDirectory {
        if files.count > 0 {
            if files[0] == fileName {
                println("sample.txt found")
                return files[0]
            } else {
                println("File not found")
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Я погуглил, но все примеры, которые я нахожу видимо не подходят для моей версии свифта, потому что сразу xcode ругается, когда я начинаю повторять примеры.

Кто может подсказать как правильно сохранять, читать, удалять временные файлы?
И ещё попутный вопрос, есть ли какая-то простая возможность очищать временные файлы после закрытия моего приложения автоматически?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведу код некоторых возможно полезных для Вас функций (язык Swift 2.3).
Например, функция для записи бинарных данных во временную директорию:

```
func writeToTempFile(fileName : String, content : NSData) {

    let tempDirectoryURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
    let targetURL = tempDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    content.writeToURL(targetURL!, atomically: true)
}
```

Аналогично работает функция для считывания данных из временной директории (помимо этого, функция устанавливает картинку для имеющегося `UIImageView`, а затем удаляет её из временной директории):

```
func readReadFromTempFile(fileName : String) {

    let tempDirectoryURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
    let targetURL = tempDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    let imageData = NSData.init(contentsOfURL: targetURL!)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        self.img.image = UIImage.init(data: imageData!)
        self.removeTmpFile(fileName)
    })
}
```

С помощью следующей функции можно получить содержимое временной директории:

```
func getAllTmpFilesList() -> [String] {

    do {

        let allTmpFiles = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(NSTemporaryDirectory())
        return allTmpFiles
    } catch {

    }
    return [String]()
}
```

А данная функция удаляет файл из времнной директории:

```
func removeTmpFile(fileName : String) {

    let tempDirectoryURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
    let targetURL = tempDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    do {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(targetURL!)
    } catch {

    }
}
```

В итоге все эти функции можно объединить в одну:

```
func loadImageFromURLAndSaveToTmp(url:String, fileName:String) {

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL.init(string: url)!) {
        (dat:NSData?, resp:NSURLResponse?, err:NSError?) in

        if (dat == nil || err != nil) {

            return
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            //self.img.image = UIImage(data: dat!) //Уберите комментарий, если вы хотите убедиться в том, что картинка была загружена корректно
        })
        //Записать полученный файл во временную директорию
        self.writeToTempFile(fileName, content: dat!)
        //Получить список временных файлов
        let allTmpFiles = self.getAllTmpFilesList()
        if (allTmpFiles.count > 0) {
            //Прочитать первый найденный временный файл
            self.readReadFromTempFile(allTmpFiles[0])
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

И вызвать её из написанного Вами кода:

```
loadImageFromURLAndSaveToTmp("http://ВашеИзображение.png", fileName: "tmpimage.png")
```

Что касается удаления временных файлов после завершения работы приложения, то здесь я бы не советовал вам этого делать, т.к. временные файлы стираются после запуска устройства и этого бывает достаточно. Однако если хотите это реализовать, вот ещё одна функция, можете её вызывать например в `applicationWillTerminate` вашего `AppDelegate` (или в другом методе `AppDelegate`):

```
func cleanTmpDirectory() {

    do {
        let tmpDirectory = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(NSTemporaryDirectory())
        for tmpFile in tmpDirectory {

            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(NSURL.init(string: "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())\(tmpFile)")!)
        }
    } catch {

    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за такой развёрнутый ответ. В данный момент проверить не могу. Чуть позже попробую и тогда отпишусь. Но надеюсь поможет. А по поводу удаления временных файлов, я как раз так и хотел, чтобы они удалялись системой автоматически. В смысле, чтобы не засорять пользователю телефон. И раз система сама об этом заботится, тогда хорошо.

Comment: В общем проверил я запись и чтение. Всё работает. Остальные методы тоже думаю пригодятся. Правда у меня не совсем картинка в оригинальном формате хранится. Мне нужно её сохранять в Base64, но тут уже я думаю справлюсь (я пробовал сохранять не бинарный, а строковый формат файла, немного доработок и всё получилось). Огромное спасибо за помощь!